# How to get Internal Font Name programmatically in UWP mobile and desktop

Tags: c#, windows, fonts, uwp

I have downloaded custom font through code and want to apply it on my text view for that I want to know the exact name of font.

**Note:**

I want to know the font internal name not the font file name.let a font is abc.tff and when open the font the Name at top is "Arial", so i need the name Arial.
I have found method for pure windows 8/7 desktop applications not for UWP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I've found to extract the metadata from a font in order to find the name.

What you could do is create an observable collection that lists the data yourself... not ideal, but realistic.

```
Add(new Font("ABeeZee", "/Fonts/ABeeZee-regular.ttf#ABeeZee", "Sans Serif")
```

Then when you call the font, you can grab the data from your collection.